# Catch dynamic request content from web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, httprequest

I'm trying to catch dynamic content from a webpage. The data is displayed dynamically on the webpage after loading the content.
On one webpage the response in the console is json formatted and html for the second one.

I've tried to work with scrappy and urllib3 but did not manage to catch something else then the static data from the webpage itself.

Here is what I've tried to use with scrappy.

```
class spider(scrapy.Spider):                                                 
    name = 'myspider'                                                    
    start_urls = [url]                                                 

    def parse(self, response):                                               
        yield scrapy.FormRequest('myurl',    
                                 callback=self.write_vente,                  
                                 headers=headers,                            
                                 meta={'proxy': 'https://' + str(proxy)})    


    def write_vente(self, response):                                         
        filename = 'vente.html'                                              
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:                                      
            f.write(response.body)
```

If you know any solutions or other libraries/framework to use or even other programming language that allows me to do so

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most common used tool to scrape data from dynamic websites is [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/). Which also has good support for Python, can be used headless. Also it has loads of articles if you search for it incombination with scraping.

Scrappy does have some support for pre-loading dynamic content or using Selenium in combination with Scrappy, see: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html#topics-javascript-rendering